# How to get user geolocation in Twitter4j?

Tags: java, twitter4j

I want get the information of user geolocation in twitter using [Twitter4J](https://twitter4j.org).

I use `tweet.getUser.getLocation()` but that gives me the wrong geolocation.

```
// create ConfigurationBuilder class variables "cb"

    // Create Twitter Factory
    TwitterFactory twitterFactory = new TwitterFactory(cb.build());
    Twitter twitter = twitterFactory.getInstance();
    try {
        Query query = new Query("범죄");
        QueryResult result;
        int twittNum = 1;
        do {
            result = twitter.search(query);
            List<Status> tweets = result.getTweets();
            for (Status tweet : tweets) {
                System.out.println("===========================================================================================================");
                System.out.println("["+twittNum+"] 번째 트윗");
                System.out.println("유저이름1:"+tweet.getUser().getName());
                System.out.println("트윗장소:"+tweet.getUser().getLocation());
                System.out.println("트윗언어:"+tweet.getUser().getLang());
                System.out.println("트윗시간?:"+tweet.getUser().getCreatedAt());
                System.out.println("===========================================================================================================");
                twittNum++;
            }
        } while ((query = result.nextQuery()) != null);
        System.exit(0);
    } catch (TwitterException te) {
        te.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Failed to search tweets: " + te.getMessage());
        System.exit(-1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Since you said the location returned was `wrong`,  what location were you expecting?

Comment: I want get the real location form user. like latitude or longitude

Comment: If you want the user's location, you're going to have to use a different approach. GetLocation from Twitter4j returns the location of `tweet` not `user`. 
`tweet` location is not `user` location. It is not wrong. It's just not you want desired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean by wrong location?

Twitter4j is just an implementation on Java of the Twitter APi, and from the [documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/overview/api/users):

> **location**: *Nullable*. The user-defined location for this account’s profile. Not necessarily a location nor parseable. This field will occasionally be fuzzily interpreted by the Search service.

That means that `tweet.getUser.getLocation()` will get you the location from the user and it is not a *geolocation* (like on some tweets). You can't get the real location from an user, the location field is an input from the user (an `string`), so it could be anything. If you get stuffs like *in your heart*, *below the bridge* or something not so specific like *Korea* or *the world* that doesn't mean that is wrong, it just what people wrote.

Comment: Is there any other way to get the user's location like Public IP address or something like that? anything that can be translated into Spatial data.

Comment: There is no way from Twitter. At least from Chile around 50% of the users put Chile on the location Field, and a fewer number put a more accurate location. You will need to extract the info from that field and work it by yourself.